# Excel VBA importing data value as text

Tags: excel, vba, text

I am new to VBA and I am trying to automate importing data into excel.  The VBA tutorial got me 95% there but I am losing leading 0's.  I am unsure of where or how to edit my VBA to ensure leading 0's are maintained.  Column A is where Im losing the 0's but if it's simpler the entire file can be imported as text value.

My VBA is below.

```
Sub RSupplyOutput()

Dim fileToOpen As Variant
Dim filefilterpattern As String
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Dim wbtextimport As Workbook


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

filefilterpattern = "Text Files (*.txt; *.csv), *.txt; *csv"

fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilterpattern)

If fileToOpen = False Then
    ' Input cancled
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
Else
    'we have a file to open
    
    Workbooks.OpenText _
                Filename:=fileToOpen, _
                StartRow:=2, _
                DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                Tab:=True, _
                FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlTextFormat))
                                                         
                                                         
    Set wbtextimport = ActiveWorkbook
        
    'Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
     Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RSupply")
    
    wbtextimport.Worksheets(1).Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Copy wsMaster.Range("A3")
        
    wbtextimport.Close False
    
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe you need to use the `FieldInfo` parameter of [`OpenText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext). Also, the macro recorder is likely helpful here.

Comment: If utilizing the FieldInfo, where in the VBA would this take place?  At  the "Set wbtextimport" seems to be the area I would need to make declerations.

Comment: You would use it where you're using `.OpenText`? e.g. after `Tab:=True`?

Comment: Corrected VBA and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Here is Edited Code:

```
Sub RSupplyOutput()
Dim fileToOpen As Variant
Dim filefilterpattern As String
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Dim wbtextimport As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
filefilterpattern = "Text Files (*.txt; *.csv), *.txt; *csv"
fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilterpattern)
If fileToOpen = False Then
    ' Input cancled
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
Else    
    Workbooks.OpenText _
                Filename:=fileToOpen, _
                StartRow:=2, _
                DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                Tab:=True                 
    Set wbtextimport = ActiveWorkbook        
    'Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
     Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
     wbtextimport.Worksheets(1).Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Copy wsMaster.Range("A3")
    wsMaster.Columns("A").NumberFormat = "00000" '**Number of Zeros As per your original Data**        
    wbtextimport.Close False    
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```